# Error Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior

Tags: java, android

I have error at this line showing

**All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

its my

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akhilkumar.chitchat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: which android studio u can use ?

Comment: @MohammadAli android 3.1.2

Comment: follow my answer and go in setting if Offline Mode is Enable then please go in setting and Mode is disable @CharyJagdeesh

Comment: Try this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top] I hope it may helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes because you can use older version so simply update your version dependencies.

**Change :**

`compileSdkVersion 26` or `targetSdkVersion 26`

**TO**

`compileSdkVersion 27` or `targetSdkVersion 27`

**Also Change :**

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

`implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'`

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

**`Sync..`** and **`Clean & ReBuild`**

Comment: Thnaks a Lot bro, its working fine after a little bit chnages

Comment: you are welcome and my answer work for u then select as a right answer  @CharyJagdeesh

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by doing this by simply changing

implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

**To**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

I hope this helps... also do a gradle update
specifically for react native navigation v2

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.akhilkumar.chitchat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```